# Google apps reinstall after uninstall

Tags: root

Hello everyone and thank you in advance,
I have an estar Gemini tablet, in which I have flashed the firmware, and installed kingroot. I need to uninstall every app that it has (except the apps needed). For some reason the GooglePlayStore, PlayMovies&TV and GoogleMaps simply reappear whenever I uninstall them. Only these 3 apps. Is there something I can do?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the apks of system apps in the */system/app* folder and the */custpack/app* folder, as well as the protected apps' apks in the */system/priv-app* folder([Source](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28231)).

My advice would be to navigate to those directories with a file explorer ([the free version of ES File Explorer will do](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)), delete the apks of the aforementioned apps and uninstall them using a system app uninstaller ([this app is a good choice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en)).